# Servers with same timezone but different time

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I have 3 servers, 2 on AWS and one on Digital Ocean, and the timezone for all is set to CDT.  But when I check the current time on all 3 by using the date command via command line, none of them matches.

```
Server1: Wed Jun 12 23:36:01 CDT 2019

Server2: Wed Jun 12 23:45:51 CDT 2019

Server3: Wed Jun 12 23:38:39 CDT 2019
```

Could anyone please suggest what needs to be done here?  Thanks.

Comment: Not a programming Q. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Do you know about https://askubunut.com ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not explicitly said that you have ntp running on them, you'll need to install that.  Once that is installed and set up properly, you should show the same exact time on all of them.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  I will check that now.